# Error when getting features from tensorflow-dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, runtime-error, tensorflow-datasets

Im getting an error when attempting to load the Caltech tensorflow-dataset. I'm using the standard code found in the [tensorflow-datasets GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets)

The error is this:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in component 0. First element had shape [204,300,3] and element 1 had shape [153,300,3]. [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]
```

The error points to the line `for features in ds_train.take(1)`

Code:

```py
ds_train, ds_test = tfds.load(name="caltech101", split=["train", "test"])

ds_train = ds_train.shuffle(1000).batch(128).prefetch(10)
for features in ds_train.take(1):
    image, label = features["image"], features["label"]
```

Comment: What is the result of running `print(ds_train.output_shapes)` after the call to `tfds.load`?

Comment: `{'image': TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(3)]), 'image/file_name': TensorShape([]), 'label': TensorShape([])}`

Comment: What does the same line print if you put after the `ds_train = ds_train.shuffle(1000).batch(128).prefetch(10)`?

Comment: `{'image': TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(3)]), 'image/file_name': TensorShape([Dimension(None)]), 'label': TensorShape([Dimension(None)])}`

Comment: Is it possible you accidentally ran the `ds_train = ds_train.shuffle(1000).batch(128).prefetch(10)` line twice without clearing your python environment first? From the outputs, it shows that `tfds.load` doesn't prebatch the data (and it shouldn't), but your error message shows that the code is trying to batch the whole dataset instead of the single samples. Does the problem still happen if you restart the python interpreter and run the lines as you show them without anything else in between?

Comment: I restarted the pycharm environment with the 'invalidate cache and restart' option. Then rerun the code. Got this error slightly different shapes here `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in component 0. First element had shape [203,300,3] and element 1 had shape [174,261,3]. [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]`

Comment: did it again and got the same error with another different shape `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in component 0. First element had shape [300,262,3] and element 1 had shape [300,206,3]. [Op:IteratorGetNextSync]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that the dataset contains variable-sized images (see the dataset description [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/blob/master/docs/catalog/caltech101.md)). Tensorflow can only batch together things with the same shape, so you first need to either reshape the images to a common shape (e.g., the input shape of your network) or pad them accordingly.

If you want to resize, use [tf.image.resize_images](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_images):

```
def preprocess(features, label):
  features['image'] = tf.image.resize_images(features['image'], YOUR_TARGET_SIZE)
  # Other possible transformations needed (e.g., converting to float, normalizing to [0,1]
  return features, label
```

If, instead, you want to pad, use [tf.image.pad_to_bounding_box](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/pad_to_bounding_box) (just replace it in the above `preprocess` function and adapt the parameters as needed).
Normally, for most of the networks I'm aware of, resizing is used.

Finally, map the function on your dataset:

```
ds_train = (ds_train
            .map(prepocess)
            .shuffle(1000)
            .batch(128)
            .prefetch(10))
```

**Note**: The variable shapes in the error codes come from the `shuffle` call.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I assume there is no easy way to reshape or pad ?

Comment: Sure there is! Let me add tha to the answer

Comment: Thanks, so much :)